# JQUERY Refined Selection

Tags: jquery

I wanted to ask about the best way to write this JQUERY code.
I have DOM structure like this:

```
 <div id="chatCenterMembers">
   <div id="adam" class="chatmember 100">
      <div class="newchatmessage" style="display: block;"></div>
   </div>
   <div id="steven" class="chatmember 101">
      <div class="newchatmessage"></div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

I want to extract a list of userid's - eg: 100, 101 class names into array where the DIV with class "newchatmessage" has the style set to display block - eg: its visable.

I can do it with a $.each loop but its appears inefficient.

Is there a better way? thx

Comment: To begin, you have 2 ids set to "username". If you want to use this id many times, use class instead.

Comment: username was just generic... would look like this as live code... is there a way to extract the useridXX for those with newchatmessage and a display block set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could collect all needed visible elements just like that:

```
$(".chatmember .newchatmessage").filter(":visible").each(function() 
{
    //Extract here any information you want, i.e. 
    //this.className.match(/[0-9]+/) 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$('.newchatmessage').map(function(){
if ($(this).css('display') == 'block')
  return $(this).parent().attr('class').replace('chatmember ','');
}).get();
```